# PHP header attachment download corrupts ZIP file

Tags: php, download, zip, attachment

I have a file like "983Y4938920820894838947" on my server, and I'd like the user to save it as "subject.zip".

Using header location makes downloading work and the file is not damaged.

Whenever i use the headers with attachment, content type and the new filename, the download zip file is corrupt (I think?).

Whenever I open the ZIP file (e.g. test.zip), it makes a new file called test.zip.cpgz. I assume this is mac's way of saying the file is corrupt.

I'm using the following code

// Download the ZIP File

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . stripslashes($new_filename) . '"');
readfile($filename);
```

This makes the file corrupt, while the below code works perfectly (but doesn't change the name):

```
header("Location: $filename");
```

I tried other headers without any success. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had an echo. The echo made the zip corrupt. So it makes sense that it only worked the header location and not the regular headers for changing the filename. Removing the echo fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a header there, if you dont specify the content length, the browser will not know what the size of the file is:

```
header("Content-Length: {{replace.with.your.file.size}}");
```

Maybe this will solve your problems.

Comment: I did this as my first attempt but it didn't work either, unfortunately.
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_filename));